# How to get email status using sendgrid api c#?

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I need get each email status whether it is delivered, bounces, etc.,

Only i'm able to getting the total count of each status. But i need to get by each email id or message id(After sent).

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished using SendGrid's EmailActivity API.  You have to purchase "Additional Email Activity History" on your account in order to access this API.  I think it's an extra $5/month at time of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need SendGrid's [Event Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) implementation. They do not have a per-message "pull" method, but the Event Webhook is a near-live "push" method, which will send you all the data/events from all your messages as they happen.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
Is there way to get status after email sent whether the email status is delivered, bounced, dropped or opened?

Comment: The Email Activity page in the UI shows short-term activity, and you can search the address. It's a historical log, so it could have a Processed, Delivered, and Opened, or anything like that, so the most-recent event on that address is what matters. The only caveat is that if you send more than one message to that address, they'll all be there.

Comment: Thanks. It need to get this from api(c#). do you have any idea?

Comment: There's no way to query Email Activity via API. It's a UI-only, for short-term checks on delivery & engagement. For in-depth data, you need to implement the Event Webhook.